# Как посмотреть от кого создалась ветка?

Tags: git

Создал я ветку `git checkout -b name`, и есть подозрение, что она не от мастера отпочковалась у меня, а от одной из веток. Как узнать, кто родитель ветки?

Comment: Посмотрите кто родитель первого коммита. Если ни одно коммита нет - просто посмотрите, на каком коммите ваша ветка.

Comment: Используя любой GUI для гита, который красиво и понятно рисует дерево

Comment: @Monk а как посмотреть кто родитель коммита?

Comment: @fosh4455, получить хэш родителя можно через `git log -n 1 --pretty="%P"`

Comment: @iksuy у меня  GitHub Desktop стоит, что-то я не наблюдаю там где дерево посмотреть, просто список веток есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы ещё ничего не фиксировали в текущей ветке, то можно глянуть на список всех веток и посмотреть, у какой пары совпадает хэш.

```
git branch -v
```

В целом, все ветки равноценны, и вы среди таких пар с большой вероятностью обнаружите искомое название.

---

А такая команда нарисует вам в консоли дерево фиксаций, выполненных в рамках вашего репозитория, вместе с именами веток.

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

Comment: О! Забыл про граф :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: в `.gitconfig` в раздел `[alias]` можно добавить: `lol = log --oneline --decorate --graph` чтобы не забыть

Answer (score 2):

на Ubuntu можно попробовать этот сниппет:

`git show-branch | grep '*' | grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" | head -n1 | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/' | sed 's/[\^~].*//'`

100% батя гарантирован))

Comment: Работает. Показало именно то, что нужно. Смотрел в Git BASH на Windows 10. Ставил себе Гит нагуглив по словам "Git for windows".

Comment: У меня на Ubuntu 20 получаю ответ skip actions

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вполне подойдёт

```
git log -n 2
```

Comment: Мне эта команда помогла)

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотреть краткий хэш родительского коммита:

   ```
   git log -n 1 --pretty="%p"
   ```
2. В списке веток найти нужный хэш

   ```
   git branch --list -v | grep "1234567"
   ```

   или в Windows ВНЕ git bash (причём кавычки обязательны)

   ```
   git branch --list -v | find "1234567"
   ```

Comment: grep не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: @fosh4455, упс.. Это либо под линукс, либо для тех, кто линуксовый пак утилит установил. Дополнил вариантом для cmd.

Comment: Что поиск должен показать? Ввожу первую команду, есть ответ, ввожу его во вторую, например `find "bb57633g"` и в ответ ничего

Comment: @fosh4455, пустой результат означает, что такой ветки, соответствующей этому коммиту вообще нет.