# git список всех дочерних веток

Tags: git, git-branch

Мне нужно пройтись по всем веткам ответвлённых от ветки `X` и смёрджить в каждую из них мастер ветку

В поисках информации нашёл ответ на ровно [противположный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704064/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0). Там была идея с тем чтобы по команде `git branch -v` вывести все ветки и смотреть у кого совпадает хэш. Но дело в том что проект ну очень большой и веток 100500 глазами по всем пройтись - не вариант.

Дополнительно могу сказать, что работаю на `Fedora Linux 35` так что `bash` командам так же буду рад, если они тут применимы. Очень желательно обойтись без UI т.е. нужно решение чисто консольными командами, конечно, это правило можно игнорировать если по другому никак))

Comment: Получить список - `git branch --contains=X` если нужны и remote ветки, то добавьте опцию `-a`.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Когда так пишу, то он выводит только саму ветку `X`, а если добавляю опцию `-a`, то выводит саму ветку `X` и ремоут верисю этой ветки

Comment: Объясните, что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите "ветка ответвленная от ветки Х". Думаю, тут есть недопонимание.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA А что именно не понятно?) Есть ветка `X`, на основе этой ветки были созданы куча других веток (т.е. ответвлялись от `X`). Приехали важные изменения в мастер ветку, которые надо влить во все ответвлённые от `X` ветки, включая саму ветку `X`

Comment: Непонятно строгое определение "ответвленной ветки" :) Если `git branch --contains=X` не показывает искомые ветки, то это значит, что X уже сдвинулась, т.е. там есть новые комиты, не слитые в искомые ветки. Вам нужны ветки, которые имеют с X общего предка не слитого в master?

Comment: Ну вообще говоря сам `X` создавался от ветки мастер, но его пока не вливали в мастер, потому я ответвлялся от `X` и доделывал новые фичи в этих ветках. Раз уж коммиты так важны, то думаю стоит уточнить, что каждый раз создавая новую ветку из `X`, я сначала в ветку `X` вливал свежий мастер ветку. И всё было окей, пока не приехали в мастер изменения, которые конфликтуют с измененями в `X`. В самой ветке `X` всё решил, осталось влить эти же изменения во все ветки, которые до сих пор ответвлялись от ветки `X`. Если нужны ещё сведения, скажите дам ещё больше информации

Comment: У меня вопросов кроме тех, что заданы выше нет. Для ясности: в git не хранится информация о том, какая ветка от какой порождена. У вас есть неформальное определение "ответвленной ветки", чтоб написать программу нужно формальное определения, которого я не знаю, и высказал выше предположение о том, каким оно может быть. Вы, очевидно, его тоже не знаете, думаю, вам стоит проверить определение, которое я выше сформулировал, и если это оно, то с этим можно работать, т.е. сделать соответствующую команду/скрипт.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Я честно не понимаю, что значит формально определение ответвленной ветки. Я просто запускал команду `git checkout -b branchName` в ветке `X`. Если есть другие способы создания ветки, то я о них не знаю :) Наверное потому и путал вас

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136716/discussion-between-roman-stop-ru-aggression-in-ua-and-eziomercer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу решение задачи примерно так.

1. Найти первый коммит из ветки X, который не содержится в master. Все ветки, содержащие этот коммит будем считать ответвлёнными от X. Командой `git log --oneline master..X` находим все коммиты из X. В выдаче нужно найти самый нижний, например, при помощи tail: `git log --oneline master..X|tail -1`
2. Найти все ветки, содержащие этот коммит, но не содержащие последний коммит из master: `git branch --no-contains master --contains …`, сюда подставить коммит, найденный на шаге 1.

UPDATE

Вам в комментарих задали очень важный для понимания вопрос: что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите "ветка ответвленная от ветки Х"?

Технически в git ветка — это указатель на один коммит.
Логически — все коммиты, являющиеся напрямую или опосредованно предками коммита, на который указывает ветка.
Но чаще всего программисты под веткой подразумевают список коммитов, которые есть в указанной ветке, но которых нет в основной (например, в master).

Именно последнее множество коммитов будет обработано при выполнении merge или rebase. И именно это множество будет выведено командой `git log master..X` (основная ветка, две точки, обрабатываемая ветка).

Соответственно веткой, ответвленной от X я считаю любую ветку, ответвленную от любого коммита в ветке X.

Если коммит a является предком коммита b, то любая ветка содержащая b логически содержит и коммит a. Учитывая это, любая ветка, ответвленная от любого коммита ветки X содержит первый коммит ветки X. Именно этот коммит мы нашли на шаге 1. Далее по текста коммит1.

Соответственно все ветки, ответвленные от X мы находим командой `git branch --contains коммит1`

Учитывая сказанное вам о том, что, во-первых, веток много, во-вторых, вам в них все нужно вмёржить master, я предположил, что работа может занять больше одного дня. Соответственно утром второго дня вы можете захотеть получить уже не весь список, а только список тех веток, которые еще не обработали.

Если в ветку еще не вмёржили master, то ветка будет содержать предком коммит1, но не будет содержать коммит master. Если же в ветку вмёржен master, то она будет содержать и коммит1 и master.

Нам нужно отфильтровать последние, поэтому указываем дополнительный фильтр `--no-contains master`

Важно! Ветка, вмёрженная в master и ветка в которую вмёржен master - это не одон и то же!

UPDATE 2

Такая потребность обычно возникает, если в master'е был сделан какой-то важный коммит, например, багфикс. Так как при многодневной работе master может убежать дальше, то сама ветка master (её новое состояние) опять окажется не вмёрженной. Чтобы этого избежать, во всех описанных командах можно заменить master на хэш того важного коммита.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: Если не сложно ответье пожалуйста логику этих действий. Я не очень понимаю почему комита не должно быть в ветке master? Просто об этом @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA тоже говорил, но никак не доходило на что именно это влияет. И что было бы, если этот комит был бы в master? Тогда эту задачу никак не решить?

Comment: @EzioMercer, вы про первый пункт или про второй?

Comment: Без разницы. Мне интересно, почему весь алгоритм держится на том, что какого-то комита нет в master ветке? А если бы я слил ветку `X` c мастер, когда-то, тогда я не смог бы посмотреть кто был ответвлён от ветки `X`?

Comment: @EzioMercer, дополнил ответ

Comment: Ещё раз огромное спасибо вам за очень подробный ответ, теперь всё предельно ясно!